# spring-boot-kube-deployment-port80-3467990654-5c8nl 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: google-container-os

Steps followed during rolling updates:

- Create an image for the v2 version of the application with some changes
- Re-Build a Docker Image with Maven. pom.xml. Run command in SSH or Cloud Shell:

  ```
  docker build -t gcr.io/satworks-1/springio/gs-spring-boot-docker:v2 .
  ```
- Push the new updated docker image to the Google Container Registry. Run command in SSH or Cloud Shell

  ```
  gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/satworks-1/springio/gs-spring-boot-docker:v2
  ```
- Apply a rolling update to the existing deployment with an image update. Run command in SSH or Cloud Shell

  ```
  kubectl set image deployment/spring-boot-kube-deployment-port80 spring-boot-kube-deployment-port80=gcr.io/satworks-1/springio/gs-spring-boot-docker:v2
  ```
- Revalidate the application again through curl or browser

  ```
  curl 35.227.108.89
  ```

  and observe the changes take effect.

When do we come across the "CrashLoopBackOff" error and how can we resolve this issue? Does it happen at application level or at kubernetes pods level?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question to be more readable. Do I understand you correctly that you do not know where/ how the error occurred? Can you provide the information how you got the error messages you posted as question title?

Comment: "CrashLoopBackOff" happens at pod level. There are several reasons for this issue, since master memory size to pod crashing because it starts up then immediately exits. Does the pods were running before the update?